# How to order names of data frame with condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames as below:

```
ch <- data.frame(list_name=c("a","a","","b","","c","c","","d"),
                 name=c(1,2,"",3,"",4,5,"",6))
```

```
cl <- data.frame(ques=c("a","b","c"),value=c("AB","CD","EF"))
```

I want to add *ques* from *cl* with their values to *ch* data frames but it should in order as below .

```
expected_output <- data.frame(list_name=c("a","a","a","","b","b","","c","c","c","","d"),
                              name=c(1,2,"AB","",3,"CD","",4,5,"EF","","F"))
```

what I am trying is:

```
cl <- cl %>% select(list_name=ques,name=value)

ch <- rbind(ch,cl)
ch <- ch[order(ch$list_name),]
```

Thank you in advance for helping

Comment: Can you explain the logic here? How are `list_name` and `name` added in the expected output?

Comment: ques and list_name are same like a, b,c and so forth the only thing is I wanna add values from cl dataframe to ch. Like a in cl should come under a in ch with its value the same with b and other values that match

Comment: In your expected output, why is that ```list_name``` and ```name``` don't match 1:1. (ie, why does ```a``` match to all of the three ```A``` ```B``` ```AB```

Comment: @Nomad420 So sorry my bad I have updated my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to maintain the same order.

```
library(dplyr)

#Get the row numbers where you need to add a row
tmp <- ch %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  filter(list_name %in% cl$ques) %>%
  group_by(list_name) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup

#Create additional rows in the dataframe
result <- ch[sort(c(1:nrow(ch), tmp$row)), ]
rownames(result) <- NULL
#Replace result with cl values at correct position
result[tmp$row + seq_along(tmp$row), ] <- cl 
result

#   list_name name
#1          a    1
#2          a    2
#3          a   AB
#4                
#5          b    3
#6          b   CD
#7                
#8          c    4
#9          c    5
#10         c   EF
#11               
#12         d    6
```

Answer (score 1):

@MaxMiak, you are almost there.

I am not sure what the purpose of the "empty" lines in `ch` are, but I take it these are placeholders for the "position" you want to see the injected data end.

I see you are using `{dplyr}`'s `select()` ... you can elegantly solve your problem with `{dplyr}`:

```
library(dplyr)

#---------- your data
ch <- data.frame(list_name=c("a","a","","b","","c","c","","d"),
                  name=c(1,2,"",3,"",4,5,"",6))
cl <- data.frame(ques=c("a","b","c"),value=c("AB","CD","EF")) %>% select(list_name=ques,name=value)      # you may use rename() here

#---------- appending cl to ch
ch <- bind_rows(ch, cl)      # bind_rows() is dplyr's rbind()
ch
```

This yields a dataframe with the "empty" rows and the new rows added at the bottom.

```
   list_name name
1          a    1
2          a    2
3                
4          b    3
5                
6          c    4
7          c    5
8                
9          d    6
10         a   AB
11         b   CD
12         c   EF
```

You then try to order. With `{dplyr}` you can use arrange here.
As the results shall be ordered by group ... `group_by()` will help.
When arranging, tell `arrange()` that you want to have this arranged per group!

```
ch <- ch %>% 
  group_by(list_name) %>% 
  arrange(list_name, .by_group = TRUE)     # enforce order per group! (default is FALSE!)
```

This will get you:

```
 ch
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   list_name [5]
   list_name name 
   <chr>     <chr>
 1 ""        ""   
 2 ""        ""   
 3 ""        ""   
 4 "a"       "1"  
 5 "a"       "2"  
 6 "a"       "AB" 
 7 "b"       "3"  
 8 "b"       "CD" 
 9 "c"       "4"  
10 "c"       "5"  
11 "c"       "EF" 
12 "d"       "6"
```

The sort order is natively numbers than alphanumerical. If you need another order, think about adding a column with ranks, etc. This way you can reshuffle the order to your liking.

To get rid of the "empty" rows: `ch <- ch %>% filter(list_name != "")`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to "inject" an additional row after each group of letters in column `list_name`. As an additional difficulty, the blank lines after each group should be kept by request.

Here is a solution which uses the `rleid()` function to create groups of consecutive runs of identical values of `list_name` and *appends* the matching row(s) of `cl` for each group after the rows of `ch`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ch)[, cbind(grp = rleid(list_name), .SD)][
  , rbind(.SD, setDT(cl)[ques %in% list_name], use.names = FALSE), by = grp][
    , -"grp"]
```

> ```
>     list_name name
>  1:         a    1
>  2:         a    2
>  3:         a   AB
>  4:               
>  5:         b    3
>  6:         b   CD
>  7:               
>  8:         c    4
>  9:         c    5
> 10:         c   EF
> 11:               
> 12:         d    6
> ```

#### Explanation

For demonstration, we can keep the `grp` column:

```
setDT(ch)[, cbind(grp = rleid(list_name), .SD)][
  , rbind(.SD, setDT(cl)[ques %in% list_name], use.names = FALSE), by = grp]
```

> ```
>     grp list_name name
>  1:   1         a    1
>  2:   1         a    2
>  3:   1         a   AB
>  4:   2               
>  5:   3         b    3
>  6:   3         b   CD
>  7:   4               
>  8:   5         c    4
>  9:   5         c    5
> 10:   5         c   EF
> 11:   6               
> 12:   7         d    6
> ```

We can see that each empty line forms a separate group. As `cl` does not have an empty value `""` in the `ques` column there is nothing to append.

Comment: Thank you Uwe for time and explanation it was helpful in its own way. GOD bless you